# Count If monetary number in row match in 2 columns

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have reviewed the suggested matches here and don't se exactly the fit...
 - and I know I have successfully done this in the past!

This is a Sales Price vs Sold price count if the (2) match.

I'll use the data for future percent data reporting.

```
ColumnC   ColumnD
Priced    Sold
$500      $250
$125      $125
$50       $15
$1000     $1000
```

the count should show  (2) I this instance.

Using MS Excel 2010

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT(), it will iterate and test each row with the TRUE matches being counted as 1 each and False as 0 each:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B5=C2:C5))
```

[image]